# How do I trigger a segue to show a specific view, when not in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS app, I have a socket server that communicates with an online app; sometimes events occur online, and I need to modify the view on the connected handset.  I have 3-4 View Controllers in my app, one of which is "Login".  I need for example, to be able to kick people back to Login, from any of the other views.

How, from a 'not a UIViewController' class, do I "show a view" with a specific ID programmatically?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still should "show a view" from a view controller class. The question should be - how do I get notification about something that happened outside?

And the answer for that would be to use iOS `NSNotificationCenter` and `NSNotification` classes to broadcast something within your application. See Apple reference for NSNotificationCenter:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks for pointing a neophyte in the right direction; ramping up fast, nice language.

Answer (score 1):

Check out unwind segues. These are specifically for this type of behavior. This will allow you to pop back easily to any viewController in the stack via a segue.

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2014/04/unwinding/

Generally you would utilize a protocol / delegate for this type of scanario to call back to the another class which is also another option.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Comment: I awarded the notification approach, but I'll definitely read up on what you linked.  Would these segues allow me to "jump", the unwind seems to understate a 'sequence'.